# How to upload custom emoji in bulk

Tags: emoji, mastodon, mastodon-py

I am testing a #Mastodon instance and want to upload a set of emojis.  Is there a way to do that?  Or do I have to do it one by one?

I understand I can copy the ones that appear on my federated feed, but I have a set of 110 custom emojis that I need to upload.  I haven't seen a Mastodon instance with the same emoji I want to use.  (Meesier Celestial Objects all 110 of them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably already figured this out what with this being seven months old, but I landed here and figured I'd give a pointer to the next person who lands here.

The official docs point to doing [tootctl emoji import](https://mastodoncn.netlify.app/en/admin/tootctl/#emoji) from the CLI after putting them all into a .tar.gz.

If you're on something like masto.host you probably don't have CLI access, and will have to do them all manually, ugh. I just opened a [feature request](https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/issues/26263) for the ability to upload a zip.